# In EmEditor, how to filter for lines matching across columns?

Tags: emeditor

To clean sentence pairs (source/target language) to train a machine translation (ML) model, I want to filter out rows where source=target. Does this require a macro?

In Excel, e.g., you can match/compare strings across column A and B in row 3 with formula “=A3=B3”. Matching strings result in TRUE. Non-matching strings result in FALSE.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHQ4B.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your question is: Suppose you have a text like below:

```
Source,Target,
Database,Database,
Database,Datenbank,
```

Then, you want to add the third row like this:

```
Source,Target,FALSE
Database,Database,TRUE
Database,Datenbank,FALSE
```

If this is correct, you can use **JavaScript** replacement expressions in the **Replace** dialog of EmEditor.

1. Click the third empty column heading to select the whole third column.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to display the **Replace** dialog box.
3. Click the **Advanced...** button to display the **Advanced** dialog box. Click **Reset** and **OK**. This step ensures the advanced options are set as default.
4. In the **Replace** dialog box, Enter:

- **Find:** `.*`
- **Replace with:** `\J cell(-2)==cell(-1) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"`

5. Make sure the **Regular Expressions** and **In the Selection Only** options are set.
6. Click **Replace All**.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the replacement expression, Yutaka!